# Convert nested T-SQL select query to linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have the following SQL query which I am trying to translate to a LINQ query:

```
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    SUM(Bills.BillAmount) AS BillAmountTotal,
    SUM(COALESCE(Pay.Paid, 0)) AS [Payments]
FROM
    Bills
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         BillId,
         SUM(PaymentAmount) AS [Paid]
     FROM 
         BillPayments
     GROUP BY
         BillId) Pay ON Pay.BillId = Bills.Id
GROUP BY
    CustomerId
```

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:linq] tag and act accordingly. Also, to make this question answerable, show your class model and your first efforts, so we can see where in the process you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following code :

```
 var pay = from p in db.BillPayments
                      group p by new { p.BillId } into g

                      select new
                      {
                          payKey = g.Key,
                          TotalPayments = g.Sum(p => p.PaymentAmount)

                      };


 var query = from c in db.Customers
                            join b in db.Bills on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                            join p in pay on b.Id equals p.payKey.BillId into cs
                            from xx in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            group new { c, b, xx } by new { c.Name, c.MobilePhone, c.Id, c.CustomerCode } into g

                            select new
                            {
                                Received = g.Key,

                                TotalPayment = g.Sum(p => p.xx.TotalPayments == null ? 0 : p.xx.TotalPayments),
                                TotlalBilling = g.Sum(p => p.b.BillAmount),

                                GrandTotal = g.Sum(p => p.b.BillAmount) - g.Sum(p => p.xx.TotalPayments == null ? 0 : p.xx.TotalPayments)


                            };
```